# Possible to transition from `InMemoryWebApiModule` in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I have implemented a project based on the "Tour of Heroes" [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).  I have made it to the point where I want to start hitting my real REST backend, but ideally I'd just want to do this operation by operation.

I updated the `post` call to use the URL for my REST service, as follows:

```
create(hero: Hero): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.http
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/heroes", JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => return res.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The problem is, this still just hits the `InMemoryDbService` provided by the `InMemoryWebApiModule`.  In fact, it doesn't matter what the URL is I supply - as long as it ends in `/heroes`, it works.  I can put in any port number, any path, and any IP (as long as it is a parseable URL that ends in `/heroes`).

I expected that the `HttpModule` would work normally and the `InMemoryWebApiModule` would only get hit when the URL resolved to the application's URL.  Apparently this is not the case and somehow just having `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)` in your module imports changes how `Http` works (from what I can tell).

**So my question is** - is it possible to continue to use the `InMemoryWebApiModule` to host mock services while you transition to a real service?  How would you modify the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial to do this for a single operation?

Comment: Confirmed that removing `InMemoryWebApiModule` from my module imports changed this to work as expected and I can now hit my external REST interface.  Still would love to be able to do both at the same time although in reading the documentation at [Angular2 HTTP](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) it seems that the entire `XHRBackend` is replaced, which suggests it would not be possible to use it at the same time.  Sad as it was good for testing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass options configuration object to the  `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot`. One of the configurations is `passThruUnknownUrl`. Set that to `true`, and it will use the normal `XHRBackend` if the collection in the mock data can't be found

```
imports: [
  InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(MockData, {
    passThruUnknownUrl: true
  })
]
```

So during you development, as new collections get created on the backend, you can start removing them on the front-end

```
createDb() {
  let cats = [];
  let dogs = [];
  return {
    cats,
    // dogs
  }
}
```

Originally, the in-memory would handle the URL `/api/cats` and `/api/dogs`. But lets say that the `dogs` collection is now created on the backend. You can just remove `dogs` from the above returned collections, and now the in-memory will forward those calls to the normal `XHRBackend` so the XHR call is made.

Comment: Ah!  Such a useful feature I'm surprised it isn't the default.